# Looking how I can populate narrative data against a hierarchy in a Power BI matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, hierarchical-data

I have a hierarchical organisational chart against which I want to populate budget vs actual variance analysis in a Power BI report. Each level of the hierarchy has it's own narrative, the parent containing summary analysis of each child. The problem is that I can only get the hierarchy to populate the leaf nodes. Specifically, each parent displays the narrative for the first leaf element below it so only the leaf nodes display as required.

The actual dataset is fairly complex so I have replicated the problem in a [simplified *.pbix file in GitHub](https://github.com/LlewopNomis/Power-BI-Hierarchy-Narrative.git) containing hierachical data for country, state and city that demonstrates it perfectly. In the linked GitHub example, I display the narrative both as a value in a matrix visual and as a tooltip; both display the same problem. In the actual file, I will only be using the tooltip.

Keen to hear if anyone has a workaround or other solution to enable each level of a hierarchy to display its actual narrative, rather than that of the first leaf node.

Answer (score -1):

I overcame this problem by including a layout that imitated a hierarchy with a measure filtering the narrative accordingly to return the correct narrative at any level of the hierarchy when scrolling over.

It takes a little extra work but does perform perfectly. The formatting of the imitated hierarchy isn't great; In the production I am playing with conditional formatting using the value of the Level column but haven't got something I'm 100% happy with yet hence haven't included.

[Here's the link to the Github repo.](https://github.com/LlewopNomis/Power-BI-Hierarchy-Narrative/tree/main)